# Can I use webSockets on my php web app?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm running a simple web app on my server 
It's a Mediatemple Ubuntu, PHP, apache, mysql 
semi-pro server so i can install whatever i want.

My app is simple, imagine a list of items. and users that can add more items to this list.
I'd love to refresh in real time, like a chat.

I'm running a simple setInterval with `ajax` on javascript but it seems not an elegant solution...

Can I install `nodejs` / `socket.io` or... what else can i do?

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason why you can't implement WebSockets in PHP.  Apache and PHP will certainly handle a socket-type connection.  You won't use `node` (I mean you could, but why complicate your environment), you would use something like `ratchet` or another PHP socket library.  Then use `socket.io` on the client side to make/maintain the connection.

You will also need some sort of event emitting solution in your server-side, such as Kafka, to get the data that has been updated.  This can get complicated quickly, but it's totally doable.